# Setting same axis in all subplots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, analysis

I want that all 6 subplots of my data have the same values on the y-axis (for better comparison):

I have the following code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(15,15))

axs[0,0].plot(drawdown[['Monthly Return Q1']] )
axs[0,0].set_title('Monthly Return Q1') 
axs[0,0].set_ylabel("percentage") 
axs[0,0].grid()
axs[0,0].set_xlabel("Years")

axs[0,1].plot(drawdown[['Monthly Return Q2']] )
axs[0,1].set_title('Monthly Return Q2') 
axs[0,1].set_ylabel("percentage") 
axs[0,1].grid()
axs[0,1].set_xlabel("Years")

axs[1,0].plot(drawdown[['Monthly Return Q3']] )
axs[1,0].set_title('Monthly Return Q3') 
axs[1,0].set_ylabel("percentage") 
axs[1,0].grid()
axs[1,0].set_xlabel("Years")

axs[1,1].plot(drawdown[['Monthly Return Q4']] )
axs[1,1].set_title('Monthly Return Q4') 
axs[1,1].set_ylabel("percentage") 
axs[1,1].grid()
axs[1,1].set_xlabel("Years")

axs[1,2].plot(drawdown[['MSCI USA - ESG Leader']] )
axs[1,2].set_title('MSCI USA - ESG Leader') 
axs[1,2].set_ylabel("percentage") 
axs[1,2].grid()
axs[1,2].set_xlabel("Years")

axs[0,2].plot(drawdown[['MSCI USA']] )
axs[0,2].set_title('MSCI USA') 
axs[0,2].set_ylabel("percentage") 
axs[0,2].grid()
axs[0,2].set_xlabel("Years")
```

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
custom_ylim = (-0.35, 0)

plt.setp(ax, ylim=custom_ylim)
```

[Graphs][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NZfb.png

Comment: `plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(15,15), sharey=True)` — Please see [the fine docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib-pyplot-subplots).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to modify the ylim of each axes, you can do it separately for each one.

```py
axs[0,0].set_ylim(custom_ylim)
```

or in a for loop.

```py
for item in axs.flatten():
    item.set_ylim(custom_ylim)
```